# UIDocumentInteractionController Controller issues

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to download pdf file from webservice and open it with **UIDocumentInteractionController**.how can i do it? i use following code for download

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl/abc.pdf"]];
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];
pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

now what should i do to open it with **UIDocumentInteractionController**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can open PDF in `UIDocumentInteractionController` using bellow code This is a example of displaying pdf from `NSBundle` you can also displaying from Document directory like same as we display images. You need to full path of document and convert it into `NSURL` using `fileURLWithPath`:-

In **yourViewController.h** file:-

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
{
     UIDocumentInteractionController *documentationInteractionController; 
}
```

**In **yourViewController.m** file:-**

```
    -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];

            NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
            documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pdfUrl];
            documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
            [documentationInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }
```

Delegate of `UIDocumentInteractionController`

```
    - (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
        return self;
    }
```

[Demo link](https://github.com/swaps2k1/UIDocumentInteractionController-Demo)
happy coding... :)

Comment: Nitinbhai but my app is crash because it will return null path ...actually i download pdf from webservice and store it on document folder and try to fetch from main bundle ...

Comment: if you stored it in document directory folder and try to fatch from NSbundle then how to get path :)

Comment: yes thats the problem so what should i do? either store it on main bundle or else

Comment: store pdf  into document directory and fetch check my now edited answer